# How can i select only values bigger than 0 with sql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a mysql table which contains negative and positive values, I want to sum only the positive ones.

Comment: You're looking for the mystical powers of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @OrelBiton . . . Welcome to StackOverflow.  When you are asking a question, you should tag it with the version of the database you are using.  It is also a good idea to include sample data and results, to better communicate what you really mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sumQuery = "SELECT SUM(myNumber) AS 'mySum' FROM myTable WHERE myNumber > 0";
$rs = mysql_query($sumQuery);
$result = fetch_assoc($rs);
echo "My sum is: ".$result["mySum"];
```

As Rekire has pointed out, mysql-functions should be avoided, and you should use mysqli instead:

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(myNumber) AS 'mySum' FROM myTable WHERE myNumber > 0";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

   /* fetch associative array */
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "My sum is: ".$row["mySum"];
   }

   /* free result set */
   $result->free();
```

}

This is taken straight from http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php (I only modified the sql-statement)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT SUM(number) as total from tblname WHERE number > 0
```

Now you can use total value.